# React Router v4 nested routes

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

Fist of all React Router is very confusing to me for the following reasons. If others feel the same way, this may be useful for them or if they dont feel otherwise, their answer would be helpful to me :)

1) What is the standard way of using react router V4

- using Switch? is this even good in V4?
- using [Route config](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config) in one js file as collection?
- using route specified in the [parent component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths)?

2) If my applications has multiple big modules, How can I specify routes based on modules and combine them in the root index file? is this even a right approach to starts with?

I have my route config written this way, **how can I configure notfound(404) logic If I have my route config in this fashion, I want it to redirect to homepage if no route found.**

```
const routes = [
{
    path: '/',
    component: Layout,
    routes: [{
        path: '/users',
        component: Users,
        exact: true
    }, {
        path: '/users/:id',
        component: ViewUser
    }, {
        path: '/addUser',
        component: AddUser
    }
    ]
}, { component: Layout }
];

const RouteWithSubRoutes = (route) => (
  <Route path={route.path} exact={route.exact} render={props => (
    <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes} />
    )} />
);

export const renderChildren = (childRoutes) => {
    if (childRoutes) {
        return childRoutes.map((route, i) => {
            return <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route} />;
        });
    }
};

export const RouteConfig = () => {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          {renderChildren(routes)}
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
};
```

Comment: This is fairly opinion based.. I don't think there's a big advantage of combining routes or hoisting them somewhere up top. That was the convention of previous react-routers and most other routing libs for other frameworks. RR4 is innovative in this sense and paths "belong" to wherever they are placed. hope that helps